# How to add a field from body to a condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I use the `@StreamListener` annotation to listen to the topic. How can I add a field from body to the condition? An example of an entity that is sent to the topic:

```
public class Event {

    private String eventId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private LocalDateTime eventTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    private Entity entity;
}

public class Entity {

    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I need to filter by the name field from the Entity class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [version 3.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing), you should avoid using filtering based on the message payload. Notice these lines from the documentation:

> The preceding code is perfectly valid. It compiles and deploys without any issues, yet it never produces the result you expect.

> That is because you are testing something that does not yet exist in a state you expect. That is because the payload of the message is not yet converted from the wire format (byte[]) to the desired type

> So, unless you use a SPeL expression that evaluates raw data (for example, the value of the first byte in the byte array), use message header-based expressions (such as condition = "headers['type']=='dog'").

So, for your case, you could add one more header into your messages and filter by using conditions on your header, e.g:

```java
Message<Event> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(event)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, event.getRequestId().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .setHeader("entityName", event.getEnity().getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .build();
this.streamBridge.send("binding", message);
```

And now your condition would be `condition = "headers['entityName']=='ABCName'"`

**Notice:** Annotation-based programming model. Basically the @EnableBinding, @StreamListener and all related annotations are now deprecated from [version 3.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-preface-notable-deprecations)